# Sort <=37 days plus other requirements?

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, grouping

I have a request to sort a table the following way, looking at 1 first, then 2, then 3:

1. sample_date <= 37 days from current date (with most recent date first)
2. any text is populated field_x (blank fields should be at bottom)
3. number in number_field is sorted largest to smallest (descendingly)

Is this possible?  #1 is the issue but I also had issues with #2 where blanks came first when sorted desc.

This is sql in oracle db and will display in power builder application.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use multiple keys in the `order by`.  Your rules are something like this:

```
order by (case when sample_date <= 37 then 1
               else 2 end),
         (case when field_x is not null then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when sample_date <= 37 then sample_date end) desc,
         number desc
```

As expressed in the question, the rules are ambiguous.  Where does a row with a recent date and a null value in `field_x` go, for instance?  However the use of `case` statements and multiple keys should point you in the right direction.